# WPF : customization in datagrid

Tags: c#, wpf, datagrid

I've a `datagrid` in my `wpf` application. I've added item to it. but when i run , it show extra row at the bottom . how can i remove it? 
now my second question is that , my `datagrid` is looks very simple ,i want to customize it like this .

i want my `datagrid` looks like this 
[image]

this is my datagrid
[image]

my `datagrid`

```
<DataGrid Name="dGrid" HorizontalAlignment="Left"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top" AutoGenerateColumns="True" >

        </DataGrid>
```

this is how , i bind `data` to my `datagrid`

```
public MainWindow()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            Bind();
        }
        public void Bind()
        {
            SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection("database=Assignment;server=.;integrated security=true");
            SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("select * from Students", con);
            SqlDataAdapter da = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd);
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            da.Fill(ds);
            dGrid.ItemsSource = ds.Tables[0].DefaultView;
        }
```

Comment: Try setting [DataGrid.CanUserAddRows](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.controls.datagrid.canuseraddrows(v=vs.110).aspx) to false.

Comment: thank you sir. my first problem is solved. but how can i make my datagrid looks like above image.

Comment: That's not a simple answer. There are plenty of tutorials online on [how to style a datagrid](https://www.google.com/#q=how+to+style+datagrid+wpf).

Comment: Also the datagrid that you have added does not seem to be standard datagrid. It looks like a custom third party datagrid probably Xceed datagrid for WPF.

Comment: what is xceed datagrid , and how can i use it?

Comment: That bit at the top 'Drag a column here' makes me think it's a DevExpress grid (not necessarily for WPF - could well be the Winforms one). That said, you can certainly get the same look using the standard WPF datagrid.